# Issue with margin applied to all elements

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I'm having an issue, i have a wrapper div, with div inside it which contains another divs which are floated to the left and have a `margin-left: 30px;` This is how it looks like now

[image]

However I would like to have it so there are only margins after first and second column (So first column would be at normal position)

Should look like this (ignore difference in margin size, that's just a quick image)

[image]

How would I achieve that?

**HTML**

```
<div clas="wrapper">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="box">box 1</div>
      <div class="box">box 2</div>
      <div class="box">box 3</div>
      <div class="box">box 4</div>
      <!-- etc... -->
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not actually removing the margin, but you can apply negative margin to the container:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

or use position: relative for the same purpose:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser supports requirements you could use the CSS3 `:nth-of-type` pseudo-selector:

```
.box:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Here's an example that uses border (for demo purposes) rather than margin: http://jsfiddle.net/PdFjt/